# adding array of integers to ArrayList<int[]>

Tags: java, list, collections, processing

I have an arraylist

```
ArrayList<int[]> strokeLines = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

and a function which runs everytime the mouse is clicked which adds the current mouse position and the previous mouse position to this arraylist

```
strokeLines.add({mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY});
```

I had this code working earlier but I lost everything I wrote in the past hour, and when I rewrote this part it wouldn't work. How can I add the array {mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY} to the end of the arraylist?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new `int[]`:

```
strokeLines.add(new int[]{mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply -

```
strokeLines.add(new int[]{mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY});
```